# Delete *.tmp folders on C: drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

My Win 7 C: drive is cluttered with *.tmp folders that have resisted all of my attempts to delete them.  Is there a way to delete these folders?

Comment: Run Disk Cleanup app from Windows and it will erase a lot of temporal files you may have. I suspect some (or all) of those temps you have are from past program setups and will be cleaned up by Disk Cleanup program

Comment: What have you tried, and what error messages have you gotten? If you provide sufficient information, the cause of your problem might be identified, which in turn allows for better suggestions regarding a solution. See See [How to Ask a Good Question](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

One technique you could try is to use the Windows Session Manager's ability to delete/move files at startup.

At startup, pretty early on in boot smss.exe reads the following registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager
PendingFileRenameOperations
```

This REG_MULTI_SZ values contains pairs of entries, a 2 lines together is a move, a line with a empty line is a delete.

Information here:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc960241.aspx

The following Microsoft tools, give you the ability to list and add to this key:
https://technet.microsoft.com/sysinternals/pendmoves.aspx

In your case you probably want to add values to the key to remove them at startup. E.g. In an administrative command prompt run:

```
movefile.exe "tester" ""
```

to delete the folder/file called "tester" on the next startup.  You can review the key directly or use PendMoves to do so before rebooting.

As this runs so early at boot, there is a good chance nothing has a handle to it and it can be removed.

The other option, might be to run Process Explorer as administrator (https://technet.microsoft.com/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) and choose "Find" -> "Find handle or DLL...".  Enter the name of the file/folder that you are unable to delete.  If it appears in the next dialog then you can see the process or processes that have/has a handle to it.  It may be possible to end the process or processes to cleanup the handle(s) such that you can delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create batch file with just few lines. 
This should do the things just right:

```
rd %temp% /s /q 
md %temp%
```

If you want to create a batch file. Just make a notepad file write these lines into that. Than save and rename the "*.txt*" to "*.bat*". This always worked for me and i use it often when a customer brings PC with any problem. It's always good to clear temps sometimes.